# OnMouseRelease is acting like OnMouseClick

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have an app that is having a ball break some blocks but the game restarts when the mouse button is released instead of on a click.

I created the app so that the game starts with a mouse click. If the ball hits the bottom pane instead of the paddle, then the game is suppose to reset and the player loses a life. The paddle is also controlled with the mouse, so in theory, the mouse will still be pressed down from using the paddle when the ball misses and the game resets. Unfortunately, I can't seem to fix the issue where releasing the mouse button from controlling the paddle restarts the game. I have tried adding a forced release, counters, using onMouseDragReleased with onDragDetected, and other combinations. Below is some partial code where I included the areas I thought relevant to my issue. Some of the different aspects I tried are commented out.

```
public class BBController {
boolean start = true; //check if can start game
int pl = 0; //counter for checking mouse release
int cl = 0; //counter for checking mouse clicks
Timeline animateBall; //move ball
ArrayList<Rectangle> rec; //ArrayList to house all of the "blocks"

//GUI components
    ... 

//Start the game
@FXML void startGameWithMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if (cl == 0){ //haven't clicked to start game
        animateBall = new Timeline( //for making the ball move around
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(12),
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    int dx = 2;
                    int dy = 2;

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                        ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
                        ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);
                        Bounds b = pane.getBoundsInLocal();

                        if (hitSides(b)){ //ball hits left or right side
                            ...
                        }
                        //ball hits top of pane, the paddle, or a block
                        if (hitTop(b) || hitPaddle() || hitBlock()){
                            ...
                        }
                        if (rec.size() == 0){ //if hit all of the blocks
                            ...
                        }
                        if (hitBottom(b)){ //if ball hits bottom pane
                            //stop the bouncing
                            animateBall.setCycleCount(0);
                            animateBall.stop();
                            //next mouse click can start game if lives left
                            cl -= 1;
                            cb.setText(Integer.toString(cl));
                            /*if (pl==0){cl -= 1;}
                            cb.setText(Integer.toString(cl));
                            //reset paddle
                            if (pl > 0){
                            Event.fireEvent(pane, new MouseEvent(
                                MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,0, 0, 0, 0,
                                MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, true, true, true,
                                true, true, true, true, true, true, true,
                                null));
                            }*/




                            //if (pl > 0){pl -=1;}
                            //pb.setText(Integer.toString(pl));

                            paddle.setLayoutX(250);
                            //reset the ball's position
                            ball.setLayoutX(300);
                            ball.setLayoutY(371);
                            //lose a life
                            livesTotalBox.setText(Integer.toString(
                                Integer.parseInt(
                                    livesTotalBox.getText()) - 1));
                            if (Integer.parseInt( //out of lives
                                livesTotalBox.getText()) == 0){
                                start = false; //can't play any more
                                gameOver.setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-color: YELLOW");
                                gameOver.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }//end hitBottom
                    }//end handle
                }//end EventHandler
            )//end KeyFrame
        );//end Timeline

        if(start == true){//if lives avail & mouse events cleared
            cl += 1; //future clicks don't try to start game again
            cb.setText(Integer.toString(cl));
            animateBall.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animateBall.play();
        }
    } //end if (cl == 0)
}//end startGameWithMouseClicked

private boolean hitSides(Bounds b){ //check if ball hits sides of pane
    ...
}

private boolean hitTop(Bounds b){ //Check if ball hits top of pane
    ...
}

private boolean hitBottom(Bounds b){ //check if ball hits bottom of pane
    ...
}

private boolean hitPaddle(){ //check if ball hits paddle
    ...
}

private boolean hitBlock(){ //check if ball hits a block
    ...

} //end hitBlock

//Control the paddle
@FXML void selectPaddleWithMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
//  pl += 1; //mouse button pressed outside of starting game
//  pb.setText(Integer.toString(pl));
    paddle.getLayoutX();
}
@FXML void movePaddleWithMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) { //move paddle
    if (event.getSceneX() <= 0){ //paddle can't go beyond left side pane
        paddle.setLayoutX(0);
    }
    else if (event.getSceneX() >= 500){ //paddle can't go beyond right side
        paddle.setLayoutX(500);
    }
    else {paddle.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX());} //paddle anywhere btw sides
}
@FXML void stopPaddleWithMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
/*  if (pl > 0) {//mouse was pressed outside of starting game
        pl -= 1;
        pb.setText(Integer.toString(pl));
        //leave paddle where you released
        paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX());
    }
    else {//game needs to reset
        paddle.setLayoutX(250);
        pb.setText(Integer.toString(pl));
        //next mouse click can start game if lives left
        cl -= 1;
        cb.setText(Integer.toString(cl));
    }*/

    if (cl == 0) { paddle.setLayoutX(250); }
    else { paddle.setLayoutX(paddle.getLayoutX()); }
}

// called by FXMLLoader to initialize the controller
public void initialize() {
    ...
}//end initialize
}//end BBController
```

I click and it starts the game. Keeping the click counter keeps the game from restarting when I click the mouse a second time to control the paddle. However, none of the variations of the counters and their placements could keep the game from starting immediately on mouse release. I am using Scene Builder, and I currently have tried the following:

startGameWithMouseClicked as the Pane's onMouseClicked event
selectPaddleWithMousePressed as the paddle's  onDragDetected or onMousePressed
movePaddleWithMouseDragged as the paddles onMouseDragReleased or onMouseDragged
stopPaddleWithMouseReleased as the paddles onMouseDragReleased or onMouseReleased

I also tried making them all events of pane and none as paddle in case the dragging of the paddle back and forth caused the cursor to no longer be on the paddle when it was dragged and released.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as this is an annoying bug of my app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the mouse events always go pressed, released, click - so where I was thinking it would stop after being released from the dragging motion, the click event still has to happen. I ended up creating one variable and had it increase at the start of the game in the click event (within an if var == 0), increase and decrease on every press/release, and then the final decrease within the click event to get it back to 0 (only if the ball wasn't moving anymore) as an else statement (so when var != 0).

Here is my logic:

```
click event
  if counter = 0
    start game
    counter + 1
  if counter != 0
    if ball moving, do nothing //for if you press/release multiple times while dragging paddle
    if ball not moving, counter - 1 //next click can start game
end click event

press event 
  counter + 1
end press event

drag event 
  move paddle
end drag event

release event 
  counter -1
end release event
```